# Mongoose: Add text index to nested schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to find a user based on their `shared.username` or `shared.email` everything before the @ or `shared.fullName` do I just change `index: true` to `index: text` for each of the fields I want to text search on??

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      confirmationCode: { type: String, index: true },
      confirmationSentAt: { type: Date },
      confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
    password: {
      formattedKey: { type: String },
      hash: { type: String },
      resetCode: { type: String, index: true },
      sentAt: { type: Date },
    },
    shared: {
      avatarId: { type: String },
      bio: { type: String },
      canFollow: {type: Boolean},
      country: { type: String },
      coverId: { type: String },
      currency: { type: String, default: 'USD' },
      dob: { type: Date },
      email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true }, // <== Change to text?
      followers: { type: Number, default: 0},
      following: { type: Number, default: 0},
      fullName: { type: String }, // <== add index:text?
      gender: { type: String },
      isMe: {type: Boolean},
      language: { type: String, default: 'en' },
      location: { type: String },
      loggedIn: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      mobileCode: { type: String },
      mobileNumber: { type: String },
      twofactor: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      username: { type: String, unique: true, index: true }, // <== Change to text?
      warningMessage: { type: String, default: 'verify' },
      webSite: { type: String },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

data a sample as text

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e098adaf55332456cb733d8"), 
    "email" : {
        "confirmed" : false, 
        "confirmationCode" : "8f558eee9ac4e4119ec34c34fbe8e867c82a1b33"
    }, 
    "shared" : {
        "currency" : "USD", 
        "followers" : NumberInt(0), 
        "following" : NumberInt(0), 
        "language" : "en", 
        "loggedIn" : true, 
        "twofactor" : false, 
        "warningMessage" : "verify", 
        "email" : "Fred@gmail.com", 
        "fullName" : "Fred", 
        "username" : "Fred61", 
        "location" : "/my/profile"
    }, 
    "password" : {
        "hash" : "$2b$10$XFelKt9Gge6nF8lpwIMAYOPIfmaNyKAs0aR/VziX.v1rQ6ZVL0Bty", 
        "formattedKey" : "lmhc a5td smcr wolr wr3e 25fl 4rbr duu7"
    }, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-30T05:27:54.548+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-12-30T09:02:45.808+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the index with mongoose, mongoose isn't an index managemenet system.

Even in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) they state this like this:

> In a production environment, you should create your indexes using the
>   MongoDB shell rather than relying on mongoose to do it for you.

So you can create all your indexes in mongodb shell like this:

```js
db.users.createIndex(
   {
     "shared.username": "text",
     "shared.email": "text",
     "shared.fullName": "text",
   }
 )

db.users.createIndex( { "shared.username": 1 }, { unique: true } )
db.users.createIndex( { "shared.email": 1 }, { unique: true } )

// note that it is not a good idea to create unique index on fullname, since multiple users can have the same fullName.
//db.users.createIndex( { "shared.fullName": 1 }, { unique: true } )

db.users.createIndex({"email.confirmationCode" : 1})
db.users.createIndex({"password.resetCode" : 1})
```

This way you can remove all index and unique related options in your schema.

Comment: is it possible to make `shared.email` unique and have it text searchable?

Comment: @Bill I guess it is possible to have a text index and unique index on the same field. Can you try please?

Comment: @Bill I tried with a simple schema, and it works. Did you make it work?

Comment: @Bill  I updated the answer with all index creation code. Also  it is not a good idea to create unique index on fullname, since multiple users can have the same fullName.

Comment: I'm just wrangling with the IDE a min, it's complaining that indexes already exist etc, I'm going to drop the database and try again

Comment: @Bill yes first drop database or just the users collection (make a backup if necessary), then create a sample user document, run my index creation code, and that's all.